# HashMap with O(log(N)) time complexity operations

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, data-structures

I took a test on CodeSignal but couldn't solve this problem.

> Create a data structure that allows the following operations.
>
> insert x  y - insert an object with key x and value y.
>
> get x - return the value of an object with key x.
>
> addToKey x - add x to all keys in map
>
> addToValue y -add y to all values in map.
>
> Time complexity of each operation should be O(log(N))

I was able to make a hash map using array and LinkedList in Java. But I wasn't able to make the time complexity to O(log(N)).
In my implementation, the time complexity of insert and get was O(1) (O(N) in worst cases). And the time complexity of addToKey and addToValue was O(N) as I had to iterate all elements to modify keys and values.

What would be a proper data structure for this problem?

Comment: Are the keys and values numeric? If not, what that is mean to add x/y to all keys/values?

Comment: This is presented as a HashMap question, but this is a BST problem. Create a node with 2 int, key and value and create a BST by comparing the keys

Comment: *"addToValue y -add y to all values in map."* I doubt this can be done in less than `O(N)`, or perhaps this could be `O(1)` if you keep separately the sum of added values in another variable

Comment: @Cid Even I am thinking the same, the key must be a unique number, so only 1 key should be updated. There should not be more than one key in hashMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited to correct the answer after the helpful comments of The Vee and Tom Elias.**

You can't implement `addToKey` and `addToValue` by iterating over all the elements, since that requires, as you realized, linear time.

Instead, you can keep a `keyDelta` and `valueDelta` `int` instance variables that hold the value (or the sum of all values) that should be added to each key and value respectively. This is assuming `addToKey` and `addToValue` are supposed to add a numeric value to the keys or values.

`addToKey` and `addToValue` will only need to update those instance variables, which would take `O(1)`.

The `get(x)` operation will search for the key `x - keyDelta` and return its corresponding value after adding `valueDelta` to it.

Note that `add(x,y)` also requires a change, since key-value pairs added to the Map should not be affected by previous calls to `addToKey` or `addToValue`. This can be achieved if `insert(x,y)` will actually insert the pair `x - keyDelta, y - valueDelta` to the map.

If you use a `TreeMap` to implement the mapping of keys to values, `get` and `insert` would take `O(logN)`.

Comment: Well, you could in principle just subtract the current keyDelta and valueDelta from newly added pairs to save this approach.

Comment: I mean at the moment of their insertion, sorry. That way they will behave consistently with what's already in there in all the remaining operations.

Comment: he is right, instead of (key,value) insert (key-delta, value-delta) all the time. when you "get" you always return (value-old delta+new delta). boker tov ;)

Comment: Yes, this might work. Thanks The Vee and Tom

Comment: Hi, @Eran, thank you for your answer. Could you provide a TreeMap implementation?

Comment: @MaLong just use `java.util.TreeMap`.